# How to retrieve values from a javascript Map when we have an object as a key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to retrieve value present in a map for a particular key in a Javascript Map object:

It looks like this:

```
let group = new Map();
group = [
  [
    {
      "name": "Email",
      "displayText": "Email",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    [
      {
        "name": "GoogleGmail",
        "displayText": "Gmail",
        "description": "xyz",
        "soln": "Email"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "displayText": "Documents",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    []
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Files",
      "displayText": "Files",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    []
  ]
]

console.log(group.get({
      "name": "Email",
      "displayText": "Email",
      "description": "xyz"
    }));
```

when I do this I get undefined.
So how do we access the value

```
[
      {
        "name": "GoogleGmail",
        "displayText": "Gmail",
        "description": "xyz",
        "soln": "Email"
      }
]
```

Comment: you would have to use the same object, not an object looking the same, it's generally ill-advised using objects as keys, if you have to, you should consider stringifying them first

Comment: The keys of an Object must be either a String or a Symbol (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). So you need to change your object's structure.

Comment: @StefanN you contradicted yourself, in the link you've provided it is said that `Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value`

Comment: Used this conversation for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `group` variable is assigned a value of an array, and not a map. Here is a breakdown of your code.

*Statement 1* (assigns a map)

```
let group = new Map();
```

*Statement 2* (assigns an array, overrides the previous assignment)

```
group = [
.
.

];
```

**Edit:**
On the other hand, based on one of the comments in the question, you could do this below to get what you want. But really, it is **unconventional to use objects as keys**. See code snippet below:

```js
let obj = {
      "name": "Email",
      "displayText": "Email",
      "description": "xyz"
    };


let group = new Map( [
  [
    obj,
    [
      {
        "name": "GoogleGmail",
        "displayText": "Gmail",
        "description": "xyz",
        "soln": "Email"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "displayText": "Documents",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    []
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Files",
      "displayText": "Files",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    []
  ]
]);

console.log(group.get(obj));
```

> you would have to use the same object, not an object looking the same,
> it's generally ill-advised using objects as keys, if you have to, you
> should consider stringifying them first – Krzysztof Krzeszewski

Comment: The map constructor can take an array, which is probably what they meant to do.

Comment: In retrospect, it does appear so.

Comment: Edited the answer based on @Krzysztof Krzeszewski comment.

Comment: @RahulBhobe I am getting this set from an API and I cannot go back and say its an array when my console says its a Map

Answer (score 2):

From the code above `group` is not map it's an array

Below a example of how to set and get data from a map;

```js
let group = new Map();

group.set('a', 'foo');

console.log(group.get('a')) // would log 'foo'
```

To use a an object as the key of a map u have to store a reference to the object so you can get the value of that object using it as a reference
**Example:**

```js
let a = {a: 1} 

let group = new Map();

group.set(a, 'foo')

console.log(group.get(a)); // would log 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

General speaking, its possible to use Object as key. However, you have to make sure that you are using the original object as key to get the value, not by another object that looks the same.

```js
const group = new Map();
const o = { name: 'email' };
const k = { name: 'GoogleEmail'};
group.set(o, k);
group.get(o); // { name: 'GoogleEmail' }
groups.get({ name: 'email' }); // undefined
```

Besides, it's not recommend to use an object as the key. If you have to, use `WeakMap` instead, which has better performance:

```js
const group = new WeakMap();
const o = { name: 'email' };
const k = { name: 'GoogleEmail'};
group.set(o, k);
group.get(o); // { name: 'GoogleEmail' }
```